# SQL Server - CTE - With Intersect in recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

My goal is to find the stock symbls (Cusips) that is stored in every day for over few months.

I've a history table with the columns as 
  historydate       date
  symbol            char(100)

My goal is to find out the list of symbols, that is available every date starting from the first day which we shall assume as 2013-01-01.

For each date, there could be 1000s of symbols and the idea is to find only stock symbols that is being held from 2013-01-01 till the last date.

I tried, the following but it didn't work.

```
WITH asset_data_cte(cusip) 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT cusip 
        FROM   dbo.asset_data 
        WHERE  t = '20130101' 
        UNION ALL 
         SELECT orig.cusip 
        FROM   dbo.asset_data orig 
                INNER JOIN asset_data_cte adc 
                        ON orig.cusip = adc.cusip 
                       AND orig.t != adc.t) 
SELECT * 
FROM   asset_data_cte
```

This wasn't producing what I really wanted. Not sure, the best way to get my queries answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler query that achieves that. It checks if there's a record for each date between `@startdate` and `@enddate` (inclusive). It uses grouping and checks the count to be the same as number of days between the dates.

```
declare @startdate date, @enddate date
set @startdate = '20140101' 
set @enddate = '20140103'

select cusip
from asset_data
where t >= @startdate and t <= @enddate
group by cusip
having count(distinct t) = datediff(d, @startdate, @enddate) + 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5450d/1)